# Working with Delphi TThread

Tags: multithreading, delphi

This is the first time to try working with `Threads`, I'm trying to copy a directory using a `Thread`, so here is what I did (After I read **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451138/simple-thread-sample-delphi)**):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.IOUtils, System.Types;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
TMyThread= class(TThread)
  private
    Fsource, FDest: String;
  protected
  public
    constructor Create(Const Source, Dest: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Execute(); override;
  published
end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  MT: TMyThread;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TMyThread }

constructor TMyThread.Create(const Source, Dest: string);
begin
  Fsource:= Source;
  FDest:= Dest;
end;

destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var Dir: TDirectory;
begin
  inherited;
  try
    Dir.Copy(Fsource, FDest);
  except on E: Exception do
    ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
MT := TMyThread.Create('SourceFolder', 'DestinationFolder');
try
  MT.Execute;
finally
  MT.Free;
end;
end;

end.
```

When I click on the `Button1` I get this error message:

> Cannot call Start on a running or suspended thread

What's wrong here? I don't know much about threads,I even try:

```
MT := TMyThread.Create('SourceFolder', 'DestinationFolder');
```

Comment: Threads run in parallel to your main program. That means Thread.Execute runs asynchronously to your main program, so your 'Free' statement (attempts to) destroy the thread before it has a chance to run - hence your message

Comment: @Dsm Thanks for the information, but even without `MT.Free;` I get the same error msg.

Comment: Don't call `Execute`. The framework does that. You are just executing it in the main thread. Don't call `ShowMessage` from the thread. Can't do GUI outside the main thread.

Comment: Additionally to what David pointed out, you aren't calling any of the constructors of `TThread`.

Comment: Furthermore, you really should avoid using global variables. And there's little point in calling `inherited` in your `Execute` since it overrides an abstract method. And don't declare an variable of type `TDirectory`. The `Copy` method is a class method. Use `TDirectory.Copy`. In case you don't understand @nil's comment, you need to add an `inherited` in your thread class constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful comments.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Should I `SetFreeOnTerminate(True);` or the thred will free automatically?

Comment: `Thread.FreeOnTerminate := True`, otherwise you need to keep hold of the reference and destroy it yourself.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks again.

Comment: I'm against that free on terminate thing. Using thread pool is by magnitude better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for all guys helps with helpful comments:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.IOUtils, System.Types;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
TMyThread= class(TThread)
  private
    Fsource, FDest: String;
  protected
  public
    constructor Create(Const Source, Dest: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Execute(); override;
  published
end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TMyThread }

constructor TMyThread.Create(const Source, Dest: string);
begin
  inherited Create;
  Fsource:= Source;
  FDest:= Dest;
  Self.FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  try
    TDirectory.Copy(Fsource, FDest);
  except on E: Exception do
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var MT: TMyThread;
begin
MT := TMyThread.Create('Source', 'Destination');
end;

end.
```

Comment: You better set `FreeOnTerminate` to true inside the thread constructor to avoid a leak. And skip the `MT` variable, since referencing a thread object with FreeOnTerminate = true is not allowed.

Comment: The problem with that is that it places a constraint of consumers of the class. The other option is to create suspended and then set free on terminate from the outside, and then start the thread.

Comment: Or pass a boolean with the constructor to tell whether to set FreeOnTerminate or not.